# Using object dimensions in geometry nodes (Blender 3.x)

Tags: geometry-nodes, dimensions, blender-osm

I am looking to use map data from the [blender-osm addon](https://github.com/vvoovv/blender-osm/wiki/Documentation) to obtain the height of buildings.
When the buildings are generated, their Scales are set to 1 while their Dimensions contain "real-world" measurements. However, as soon as a geometry node tree is added, Dimension is zeroed out.
Is there a way to capture the Dimension value (specifically, `Dimension.y`) and pass it to a Geometry Node?

Comment: Could you add a sample blend file that shows the problem? ([How to add a blend file](https://blend-exchange.com/help))  or at least a screenshot of geometry nodes showing what is zeroed when you try to use it? I don't understand why the dimensions would be 0, but you should be able to use the bounding box node to get the actual values.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image]You could use the Attribute Statistic node and the Range output.

[image]

Comment: This is what I was looking for, thank you.  The only thing I added was a Separate XYZ node after the Position node.  The Dimensions remain unchanged, but this makes that moot.