# Creating bracelets with different size beads with geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

I've been wanting to make randomly generated jewelry in Blender and I really like how easily I can cycle through different seeds to see different variations of it. I've made more complicated ones with closures and pendants, but this is the simple fully bead one:

[image: My Current Bead Bracelet]

Let me know if my geometry node setup is needed, but I suppose I'm just asking for a push in the right direction.

I have a pretty simple geometry node setup to distribute different beads on a curve. The beads are currently the same size, more or less, evenly distributed instances to points. But I would like to introduce beads of different sizes, which would make them overlap if I were to do it this way.

Kind of like how there are these little beads, and then larger beads:

[image: Real necklace example]

I was wondering if there would be way to distribute these bead instances based on the size of each bead that is randomly chosen, so that there is minimal (or a controllable) amount of space between beads.

In my head I'm thinking about how I would code it as if it were a simple program -- the first one would be drawn, you would get the width of that, add it to a current width variable, add the spacing, and then iterate to the next bead a place it at that position, and repeat until you reach the end of the space possible. Though I'm not too familiar with any sort of coding within Blender as of yet.

I suppose it doesn't have to be done with geometry nodes, but I'm really liking this type of work flow.

Comment: You could use [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/271451/145249), and then [bend](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/245553/145249) it into a circle shape.

Comment: @quellenform Thank you so much for your response and sharing those two references to past posts, both which hold a lot of knowledge. I didn't have the right words to find them on my own. It seems like what I want to do is a bit beyond my skill level so a lot of the groups of nodes in those solutions go above my head. It seems I have awhile to go and a lot of trial and error before I can achieve what I'm going for, and perhaps I'll have to rethink my method overall. Thank you.

Comment: Do not give up! ...these were only examples. There are certainly simpler solutions, but the question is always how detailed you want to implement something.

Comment: Thank you for your encouraging words, I'm going to keep giving it a try of course! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try the [`Distribute Points on Faces`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/point/distribute_points_on_faces.html) node.

Your preference would be for *Poisson Disk* drop-down option.

A lot of examples distribute on plane, but I think it should work on a ring as well.

Here’s a link I found with node graphs and various extras :: https://artisticrender.com/how-to-scatter-objects-with-geometry-nodes-in-blender/