Need help with creating space between books (Geometry Nodes)
I need you guys help with creating space between the tilted books.
In my geometry nodes, it does create the "correct" amount of space when the books are rotated to screen left, but not screen right, as you can see on the second picture.
(Don't know if this helps): The geometry nodes group books->bounding box ->Vector Math Multiply changes the distance between the books. But it only does it when it rotates to the left.
What do I need to add, so that when the books rotates to the right they create same distance and don't overlap?


Does this answer your question? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/271450/

Nothing stops you from using arbitrary shapes, but for a cuboid shape rotated just around one axis, you can heavily resample one side (as a single line) to raycast on the previous books to get a very nice, "nested" (multiple books) overlapping:

The setup uses a repeat zone - it has to, because the way previous books overlap affects current book's position, so the collision calculation can't be parallelized - not without some compromises with realism.



You may spot above, that because I raycast only from the "left" side, two books almost laying flat can fail to raycast properly and overlap a little. You could of course fix this as well as raycast from all points of a book to support all arbitrary shapes - but it would by slower.
Below I subdivide from all sides of a rectangle (before it's extruded to a cuboid):


For 'production' you could maybe subdivide edges differently based on which edge it is, because you likely care more about the left edge than any other and in fact you don't care about the right edge at all. Or you may wnt to resample by length, but then you need to split the edges first and convert to curves…

Very nice! ... but you forgot the bookworms.

@quellenform https://imgur.com/a/wkbV8N2

Wow thanks! Just one question, how would I go about adding the book to this? Can i just use the group node (second pic) or would I have to insert the whole thing (first pic) in some manner? https://imgur.com/gallery/blender-knlIElD
Hopes it makes sense, I'm not that strong on the terminology

Watching this another solution with better performance came to my mind:

youtube video


Conceptually, I couldn't figure out how to make it work by using raycasts without a repeat zone: you raycast, and find the first collision - but the collision position is before the offsetting happened. You can't make an accumulated value control the accumulation value. - it seems you made it work, but I don't quite have the time to analyze this. I know it breaks for some big x size values. Mine breaks too, in my case just because I naively only use the left side of a rectangle for raycasting - is it the same for you?

I am offseting all books by its larges dimension x2, then random rotate, then rycasting all left front edges to left and front right edges to right, then selecting the shortest raycast distance in "lets call it gap ID" and accumulating this value. I am sure it can be polished even better. But still cannot find some performance workaround for my similar question https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/322996/180447

Just for clarity on what I mean, open the uploaded file and set the max x to 2.2 - then the 7th book overlaps https://i.imgur.com/lYQQPhO.png and with 3.3 also the 4th book overlaps. Maybe it's just raycast sampling not being dense enough? But it wouldn't explain this example: https://i.imgur.com/eLJWb2B.png

It is just concept idea, Iam comparing the distances in the gaps between two books only, thats probably why..:\ and even more precision for sharp angles can be added by including all 3 vertices facing the gap instead the long edge verts only...

https://imgur.com/a/C5AhaCY

Yea that's the additional edge check, however, my last example is something different. I think you can't just fix it without sequentially calculating stuff.
