Accumulate Xsize field along the multiple curves multiplied by curve radius
Result should look like the instances X size is scaled by the original curve radius and they are still correctly packed.
Approach in the image is wrong the accumulate field does not take in to the account that the previous instances should be scaled by their new position curve radius.
My idea, but I do not know how to achieve it, is to multiply "index domain spline offset point 0" Xsize by its radius then "sample curve" radius at this length and use this radius for the second point and so on... no success with the repeat zone so far... Is this possible?


This is the result on YZ axis only, I would like to know how to make it work with X axis as well:



I think this is conceptually related: Need help with creating space between books (Geometry Nodes). For what you show a repeat zone should be performant enough.

Repeat zone solution. Performance wise it is quite bad. If you have some better idea, let me know please!



Using the nested repeat zone and sampling "all curves" on seperated spline segment gives huge performance boost.

Another try with the repeat zone simulation, 25 iterations is max, if more I cannot see any change. The performance difference is 111ms old method, 2.8ms this new method. In the image below the boxes is an old method and planes the new method.
Still if the curve is too long with many radius variances, there is a slight shift difference at the end. Wondering why. (PS: boxes ending earlier as there is less than length in the old method - I ment the shift difference not this ending)


