# Geonode: Repeat an operation per instance

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'm very new to geonodes, but as far as I can see, this is a recurring problem because of the lack of a sort of loop system.

**What I want to achieve:**
I'm creating a roof made of random tiles with different widths from a collection. I want it to be entirely generated by geonodes, with parameters for width and height.

I found a solution to making a line here, complicated by the different tile widths:
Link: [Position instances of different dimensions side by side](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/270518/position-instances-of-different-dimensions-side-by-side)
[image: Geometry node setup]

**My problem:**
Now I want to expand the line to a grid, but I need a new horizontal line for each new vertical row.
Right now I can do it with a new geonode per line with another one making the final roof, but it is very(!) inefficient.

[image: Subpar solution]

Otherwise I get the same row repeatedly, as I'm not calculating the instances more than once.[image: Repeating pattern]

**Question:**
Is there a way to recalculate the instances, without duplicating the whole setup ≈50 times?

[image]
Edit: cleaner .blend

Edit 2: I've tried "Repeat Input", but I don't know how to make it work. It seems to want a geometry in- and output, but I use instances.
[image]
This outputs one row of tiles, as if it was not there. If I use more iterations, it breaks with no output.
The nodegroup is the original nodes minus the "Collection Info"

Comment: You could use a [repeat zone](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/utilities/repeat_zone.html). The "Loop Zone", as you called it, exists since 4.0. The workarounds used before 4.0 are no longer necessary.

Comment: Thanks, I see my info was outdated. Not sure how to proceed though, as I can't seem to get it to work.   
I use instances, not geometry. It seems the setup does not like that, I have tried a few workarounds, but nothing has worked.        
Outputting geometry only works on 1 iteration.      
Outputting instances breaks it, no output I can see.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem - the X problem here is clear, but the Y problem I don't understand.

Comment: @Krutzelpuntz "Geometry" is an umbrella term for anything mesh, curve, volume, or instance. Instances are geometry.

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone. Here's a .blend with the answered solution. https://blend-exchange.com/b/Jrp902vp/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

be aware, my solution just solves your repeating problem - as you wanted. It does create a new "problem" because the size doesn't fit anymore, but i think you will find out how to fix that:

[image]

result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, this is exactly what I was looking for! I was expecting the lengths to be random, I'll either cut it with a boolean, or ray-trace to an underlying plane.